# How to solve memory exhaustion？

Tags: cnosdb

cnosdb version v2.3.
When I use telegraf to write cpu monitoring data. cnosdb returns an error indicating that the memory is exhausted. How can I solve this problem?
The standard cluster configuration used by my cnosdb. The standard cpu monitoring configuration used by telegraf is written once every 10s.